# how to add struts or hibernate capabilities in Spring Source Tool?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, ide, struts

generally by using my-eclipse we add struts,hibernate and jpa capabilities to our applications/projects, like this how to add structs or hibernate capabilities to our applications using Spring Source Tool?
Spring Source tool is a version of eclipse ide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (...) like this how to add struts or hibernate capabilities to our applications using Spring Source Tool?

AFAIK, SpringSource Tool Suite doesn't provide any particular support for Struts or Hibernate, you'll have to install additional plugins for that (like [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) for Hibernate).

Comment: if you know the procedure tell me the steps.